# SSRS Manage Report in Browser Not Showing Current Subscription But is Viewable In Database

Tags: reporting-services

We have a SSRS report with a subscription.  I confirmed the report has a subscription and viewed the history by querying the ReportServer database.

When I view the subscription using a browser by choosing Manage Report, no Subscription information is shown.  No info is shown using various browsers.

We've not upgraded our version since I last viewed this report nor moved database instance.

Can someone respond as to what we can do to view the current subscriptions?

Comment: I don;t use subscriptions but the first thing I thought of was to make sure that what you are seeing is the base report and and not a linked report. Also, check if the report is hidden. You should be able to see that in dbo.catalog or if you choose to show hidden items in the web portal.

Comment: I can see the base report and manage other aspects such as properties, parameters, datasource,etc.